# Is there any paid weapon DLC in Killing Floor 2?

Tags: killing-floor-2

The original Killing Floor has some paid [weapon DLC](http://store.steampowered.com/dlc/1250) available, but all maps were free. Do all players have access to all weapons in KF2?

Comment: Update: there are now outrageously expensive DLC weapons, yes.

Comment: @HugoZink: Can you post an answer? I'll accept it.

Answer (score 4):

[Zweihander](https://wiki.tripwireinteractive.com/index.php?title=Zweihander) for the Berserker class is a "paid" weapon: in order to obtain the item you have to have [Chivalry: Medieval Warfare](http://store.steampowered.com/app/219640/) in your Steam library, but the sword can be used on a server when another player owns the weapon. The PS4 version may come with the sword.

Comment: The PS4 version does come with the sword.

Answer (score 1):

As of the [6th Sept 2018](https://forums.tripwireinteractive.com/forum/killing-floor-2/kf2-news-and-announcements/news-and-announcements-af/2324081-monster-masquerade-opt-in-beta-is-now-live-build-1069-for-clients-and-servers), there is a second "paywalled" weapon in the beta (to be released to all with the next Halloween update):

> Road Redeemer for the Berserker ( requires purchase of [Road Redemption](https://store.steampowered.com/app/300380/) )

The weapon is basically a baseball bat with some metal additions at the extremity.